# Maven not running tests from command line

Tags: java, maven, cmd, pom.xml

I am trying to run one project from cmd line using mvn test. It shows build success but not running any tests as it shows test runs:0. I have tried all the suggestions provided in stackoverflow but still its not running. Please let me know what i am missing here.

**My Maven Project:**

[image: My maven project]

**Command line Result:**
[image: cmd line results:]
**pom.xml:**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>Winium</groupId>
  <artifactId>Test</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>

  <name>Test</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
<properties>
    <junit.version>4.8.1</junit.version>
    <surefire.version>2.18</surefire.version>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.6</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.6</maven.compiler.target>
</properties>


<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.19</version>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-platform-surefire-provider</artifactId>
                    <version>1.0.0-M4</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
                    <version>5.0.0-M4</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>


  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>4.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>   
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.github.2gis.winium</groupId>
        <artifactId>winium-webdriver</artifactId>
        <version>0.1.0-1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
        <version>3.9</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.0-M4</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies> 
</project>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are mixing junit 4 (in the test definition) and junit 5 (in your pom.xml).
If it is ok to use junit 4 for you, try with the following (edited) version of your pom.xml file; I have removed the surefire plugin configurations- the defaults work ok:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>Winium</groupId>
  <artifactId>Test</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>

  <name>Test</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.6</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.6</maven.compiler.target>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>4.12</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.github.2gis.winium</groupId>
      <artifactId>winium-webdriver</artifactId>
      <version>0.1.0-1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
      <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
      <version>3.9</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```